# Extracting word document text within bullet using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Hey I need help extracting word document text (of every style) residing in heading 1 style bullet
For example:

**1. FR1:**
all text in this heading 1 style bullet

**2. FR2:**
all text in this heading 1 style bullet

My main goal is to get text from a word document within "heading 1 style" headings and save it in a list of strings like index 1 of list should contain text residing FR1 heading and index 2 should contain text residing in FR2 heading and so on.

I don't know which is more efficient way for text extracting of specific style heading whether using  heading bullets or heading name.

Comment: Most efficient is probably running a loop around Range.Find where the Find criterium is the style name (and nothing else).

Comment: Is your document thousands of pages in length? If not, do whatever works now (for example the approach suggested by @CindyMeister) and worry about optimization later.

Comment: Ok now i can find heading names with the help of the way cindy suggested. Now how to get the text within that heading after determining heading name and no sabuncu optimization is not a big issue at this time.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines on asking questions in [help]. StackOverflow is not your typical "forum" site, meaning you shouldn't "chain" questions. You should post a new question for a new topic. Also, you're expected to post code (what you've tried) and explain HOW it's not working for your. FWIW, what you typed in your Comment is not clear.